# How to save a session in golang

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I'm trying to save a logged user ID in my golang backend with gorilla sessions and securecookie.

Here is my package session :

```
package session

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var store = sessions.NewCookieStore(securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32))

//GetSessionLoggedID returns loggedID
func GetSessionLoggedID(r *http.Request) int {
    storeAuth, _ := store.Get(r, "authentication")
    if auth, ok := storeAuth.Values["loggedID"].(bool); ok && auth {
        return storeAuth.Values["loggedID"].(int)
    }
    fmt.Println("none found")
    return 0
}

//SetSessionLoggedID sets cookie session user ID
func SetSessionLoggedID(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, id int) {
    storeAuth, err := store.Get(r, "authentication")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    storeAuth.Options = &sessions.Options{HttpOnly: true, Secure: true, MaxAge: 2628000, Path: "/"}
    storeAuth.Values["loggedID"] = id
    storeAuth.Save(r, w)
}
```

I have another package that gets to verify email / password of a user that logs in.

Here is the function :

```
func (handler *UserHandler) checkPassword(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var body struct {
        Email    string
        Password string
    }
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&body)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    loggedID, err := handler.UserUsecase.PasswordMatch(body.Email, body.Password)
    if err != nil || loggedID == 0 {
        http.Error(w, "Could not authenticate user", http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }
    session.SetSessionLoggedID(w, r, loggedID)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(struct {
        ID int `json:"id"`
    }{loggedID})
}
```

The ID returned is the proper one. But the session is not saving as I would have liked.

If I add a `session.GetSessionLoggedID(r)` at the end of checkpassword function, I get "none found".

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// watch this line
if auth, ok := storeAuth.Values["loggedID"].(bool); ok && auth {
```

`storeAuth.Values["loggedID"]` is not `bool`, so `ok` is `false`, then you get "none found"

Change to

```
    if auth, ok := storeAuth.Values["loggedID"]; ok{
        return auth.(int)
    }
    fmt.Println("none found")
```